# Readily available MIR refracting material

Tags: hard-science, chemistry, optics

I am looking for a material that could serve to do the following: build a 5m x 5m wall that *looks* pretty normal (not necessarily during construction) but has the ability to transmit and refract MIR, the thermal part of the Infrared spectrum, 3µm-50µm; Could also be several layers, with the outers just providing the look and the inside being the refractive part.

The idea is to have a Fresnel-type lens that would concentrate the heat of a fire onto a fire-size point on the other side of the wall, some meters away, with the wall being impenetrable to visible light. The wall would not feel hot (does not absorb too much energy - it does not need to feel like a stone wall to the touch though, though bonus if it does), but one would be able to feel the energy radiating from it, with the added puzzlement of the hotspot a few metres from the wall.

The material & build would need to be accessible to the average (single-)millionaire. It's our current world(-ish), but if this needs something that is not available in industrial quantities but *could* conceivably be (bonus for telling why they need this stuff more than we actually do now), i'm all in.

I am aware that this might be more trivially(?) dealt with by using reflective optics on the opposing wall, or by building a reflective 'lens' like it is done for X-rays, but i'd rather like something more like a real lens.

The hotspot should have too much heat flux to remain in, but does not need to be anywhere near the radiative power of a fire.

EDIT:
The usual suspects for IR optics are not applicable. They are too expensive. Optical grade Sapphire, MagnesiumFluoride, CadmiumTelluride, they are not cost-effective for a 5x5 wall-shaped lens. They offer too much. They have low chromatic abberation, high transparency, all stuff needed for having a good picture from an optics system. What i require is far less refined: The bonfire outside has, say, 100kW radiative energy. Let's pretend about 10kW of that is impinging MIR on the outside of the 5mx5m wall-lens (.4kW/m²) . I'd like to have an 'ouch-hot' perception in the focal region on the other side. Thermodynamics say we cannot create a temperature higher than the radiative surface (fire ~ 1000°C) by focussing - but that is not an issue, humans flinch above 60°C.
My ask is this: Is there a material/product that has acceptable MIR optical capabilities while still cheap and sturdy enough to be built into a wall? If there is, e.g., blocks of non-optical-but-still-good-enough sapphire on the cheap for some reason, that is what i am looking for. Or Graglesnoffrite, the bulk material used in Swulmeniting?

Comment: Melanie Saayman, [Materials for infrared optics](https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/optomech/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2016/10/Saayman-521-Tutorial.pdf). It's a short and gentle introduction to the subject. Oh, and the peak power in the infrared light coming from a fire is [at about 4.3 µ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648273/does-fire-emit-black-body-radiation), corresponding to the emission of excited CO2 molecules. P.S. A lens cannot produce any more energy than what is actually falling on the lens; that's why we can look at a fire, although our eyes focus the image of the flame.

Comment: @AlexP very short and very gentle :D - it's actually just about IR optics,, i.e stuff that has great transparency, good for making ... optics; The lens i am talking about is 5x5m, with the fire , say,  2.5m away, that  would bring about 1/5th of the total radiative energy ( i.e 100kW range) to a smallish focal point. And i only require 'too hot to bear', so the wall-optics can be increadibly lossy compared to normal optics. That's why the ususal IR optics do not apply, they are too potent and too costly

Comment: Basic optics: for a lens to make a real image of an obect, the object must be placed at a distance greater than the focal distance of the lens. If the object is closer than the focal distance of the lens, then the image is by necessity virtual (like the image made by a magnifying glass). Now, a wall is relatively thin compared to is surface area. In other words, you want a thin lens with a diameter of 5 meters and a focal distance shorter than 2.5 meters, meaning that the optical system has an [f-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number) not greater than 1/2. Good luck.

Comment: @AlexP I'ts ye olde 'if it was easy i needn't have asked' :)  --- and keep in mind i do not want an _image_ of the fire, i.e. if someone puts a piece of wood there i do not expect a photographic representation of the fire to be burnt in, i just want a hotspot. Spherical abberation and all the other optical boogeymen be damned. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens for example of 3.7m high, 1.3m focal lenght 'lens'

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider [Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon).  Of the materials that are [transparent to infrared](https://escooptics.com/blogs/news/what-optical-materials-work-best-in-the-ir-infrared), Silicon is transparent over much of the infrared range, even though its transmissivity is not the best. It is not transparent in the visible spectrum, so you wouldn't have the disadvantage that the passers-by could see the fire through it.  It has the advantage that it is hard, rigid and would look like a polished opaque glass.  It is also relatively cheap.

[image]
Image from https://escooptics.com/blogs/news/what-optical-materials-work-best-in-the-ir-infrared

You may also want to consider [polyethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene).  This material [is used as IR windows](https://www.edmundoptics.com.au/f/infrared-ir-material-windows/12440/), it can be opaque in the visible spectrum, and compared with the material used for high quality IR windows, and it is dirt cheap.  Its drawbacks are its low melting point, softness, and flexibility, which would limit its application in shaping it to be a lens for the heat of a fire and for its use as part of a wall.  However, with sufficient distance and size of a fresnel-type lens, it could concievably work.

By mounting chunks of silicon or polyethylene in brick-like frames with hollow backs, the lens part of the wall could be hidden, presenting a flat silvery-grey (Silicon) or white (polyethylene) surface that would focus IR radiation as desired, and the frames would provide rigidity to the wall.  The frames could also concievably act as IR reflectors to increase transmission of IR that would otherwise be scattered or absorbed.

Comment: If you assume standard 11cm thick bricks, then the total material cost of a silicon wall this size is about \$54,440 whereas polyethylene would only be about \$1,950; so, both work in the budget, but polyethylene is cheap enough, you don't even need to be a millionaire to do it.